# Kali Is Fully Installed To USB. Only The Computer I Installed It On Is Picking It Up

Tags: kali-linux, bootable

I installed Kali as a FULL OS on a USB 3.0 Stick a long time back.

It runs from the USB with no issues whatsoever on the computer I used to install it.
Has done for a number of years.

However, when I try to boot the USB on other Computers, regardless of the BIOS configs I make (secure boot, legacy support, etc.), it will usually show that the USB is plugged in when I pull up the boot menu, listing it as something along the lines of "USB 3.0 (PMAP)", but when I select it, it will show a phrase to the effect of "There's no Bootable OS on here".

Is this an issue regarding the GRUB Bootloader, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you either put the bootloader on the hard drive, or put system specific configuration into the bootloader.

I suggest first figuring out which variant of grub you have used.  Try "`grub-install -help`" and seeing what the default for --target is.

If this is an EFI variant, then it probably went into partition 1 of the hard drive.  If this is `i386-pc`, well again it might have gone on the hard drive.

If it was EFI, you want to make an EFI partition on the stick and install grub to that.  If this is i386-pc, again, try installing it to the stick's disk instead of the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've had a look and you were right about the default target.
I've run grub-install /dev/sdb (the usb), and it seems to have solved the issue

Comment: 1) glad I could help.  2) it wasn't so much the target I was right about (there are only 2 [unless you count 32 vs 64 bit]) as where the first stage of the bootloader was installed.  3) For more compatibility, you can actually install both the EFI and PC-BIOS versions.  Weird but functional.  (though convincing an EFI machine to boot it can be tough.)